# Group SQL tables in SQL Server Management Studio object explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table which has approximately sixty tables, and other tables are added constantly. Each table is a part of a schema.

A such quantity of tables makes it difficult to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008. For example, I must scroll up in object explorer to access database related functions, or scroll down each time I need to access Views or Security features.

Is it possible to group several tables to be able to expand or collapse them in Object Explorer? Maybe a folder may be displayed for each schema, letting collapse the folders I don't need to use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you can apply **filters** to your object explorer views.

Find the `Filter` button and click on it

[image: Filter button]

Define your filter - filtering by object name and/or schema is possible

[image: Filter settings]

Filtered view of your objects:

[image: Filtered Object Explorer]